# Android Studio Kotlin How to print strings and where do they appear

Tags: android, kotlin

I did see the question before on "How to print to console"... I am coming from iOS/Xcode to where there is one place where all outputs and errors appear so it is a bit confusing how in android studio there are multiple places for multiple out puts.

```
print("HELLO TRYING TO PRINT")
Log.d("PRINT", "Printing this message")
```

I have tried these yet even in "Console" and switch it to "Debug" and try searching "PRINT" or "Printing this message" it does not appear. I am using a Samsung Note 8 to run this app. I have tried looking up basic tutorials on this to be explained and have yet to find any. I am just trying to use a print statement to see if a function even gets called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Android Studio choose `Logcat` at the bottom . Then from drop-down
> menu select kind of logs that you want to view.
> `TAG` is your identifier which is given by you.

- Log.e(TAG, String) (error)
- Log.w(TAG, String) (warning)
- Log.i(TAG, String) (information)
- Log.d(TAG, String) (debug)
- Log.v(TAG, String) (verbose)

**Then search for the tags at the search bar.**

[Go through this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Comment: Thank you for the link because I made the changes to match the picture and my problem was not having it set to "Show only selected application".

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

They appear in logcat, which is a system wide log of all applications.  You can see this in the command line with `adb logcat`, or in the logcat window in Android Studio (which internally uses logcat, it just displays a graphical shell over it).