# how to print to command line in android

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat

I am just trying to do some basic debugging by printing off values to the command line but when I try to nothing comes up.

I have tried using both `Log.d("test", "test")` and `println("test")` neither show up when I filter Logcat with test or tag:test I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780294/how-to-print-to-the-console-in-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212850/android-studio-kotlin-how-to-print-strings-and-where-do-they-appear) question but they didn't help.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Its probably just some little thing but I completely lost.

Comment: Can you share a Screenshow of your Android Studio log? With the Console Window open? Maybe there is some other setting in your AS that is messed up...?

Comment: @TIMBLOCKER of course I have added it to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Android Studio you can see a small Funnel for the Filter.

[image: Funnel and Tag Filter]

If you start typing `package:mine` it will only show the Log Outputs created by your Application. If you then add another parameter with a space for example `tag:test` you exclude all Log Messages without your `test` Tag. In your Image you just typed `test` which has to be `tag:test` then you are able to see that.